# How to enable the Settings panel on Windows Phone by PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I just finished my 1st WP8 app with PhoneGap, and out of sudden, I found that my app doesn't have that Settings panel(I'm not sure whether it's the right name for that part -- the 3 dots at the right bottom corner and when you clicked it, a panel shows).
This is the Setting panel(please do correct me if the name I refer to is not right and I want to know it. )
[image]

Do you know how to enable it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That area is called the ApplicationBar (when round buttons are present). The links that show up when clicking the three dots is called the ApplicationBarMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three dots you pointed -if I don't misunderstand that- is called ellipsis (you can find that word in this [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), it is part of standard Windows Phone Application Bar.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with PhoneGap/Cordova. In standard windows phone application (developed using WP SDK) showing application bar (including it's ellipsis) is as straightforward as shown in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). But at least, I found this article that could probably gives you some idea to try : [PhoneGap on WP7 Tip #4: The Application Bar](http://css.dzone.com/articles/phonegap-wp7-tip-4-application)