# Click event for the "..." three dots of the application bar to change the opacity

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I just can not find how to generate a click event for the 3-dots-button of the application bar. the start mode of it is minimized and opacity is 0. I want to change the opacity to 1 the use has clicked the three dots button to expand the bar. like so:

```
if (ApplicationBar.Mode == ApplicationBarMode.Default)
        {
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1;
        }
        else { 
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0;
        }
```

Comment: at the very right within the application bar to open and close the menu list and icon discripiton and the icons if the mode is minimized

Comment: they call it [ellipsis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21629838/2998271) btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare ApplicationBar.Mode as it doesn't change when you click ellipsis (those three dots). Thought you can surely try subscribe to [StateChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.statechanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to do something like this :

```
// in constructor
ApplicationBar.StateChanged+=ApplicationBar_StateChanged;

private void ApplicationBar_StateChanged(object sender, ApplicationBarStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.IsMenuVisible) ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1;
        else ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0;
}
```

But to make it work your ApplicationBar must have MenuItems.

Comment: Can you please tell the same thing for Windows 10?