# what is the Event for 3 dots getting clicked in CommandBar in UWP Apps?

Tags: c#, events, uwp, windows-10, commandbar

**Context building:**

I have been developing UWP app (C# & XAML) in which I am using a commandbar for displaying some options at the bottom of the page. I am using Primary as well as SecondaryCommands in the commandBar.

**What I need:**

We have 3 dots at the end. I have one function which will be called when commandbar will be "opened" & "closed". 
In this function, I need to check if SecondaryCommands menu is opened or not.
Secondly, I want to know the event name which is equivalent to StateChanged Event in AppbarButton earlier. 
for #2, already referred this: [Click event for the "..." three dots of the application bar to change the opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658283/click-event-for-the-three-dots-of-the-application-bar-to-change-the-opacit)

Note: I have searched the list which comes when I press space in Visual Studio. On SO, I got links which have discussed for earlier version of Windows. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Microsoft has explained in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) there are `Openeing`, `Opened`, `Closing` and `Closed` events for `CommandBar` and they refer to `...` 3-dots (Ellipsis).

These events get fired when you press the `Ellipsis` to open or close the `CommandBar`. I think this is what you are looking for. 
And to check the `Overflow Menu` which contains the `Secondary Commands` you will have to check if the `CommandBar` has any secondary commands available with `Opening` or `Opened` event.

Let me know in comments if this is not what you need.

Comment: Ya. One part(events fired on pressing ellipses) is solved with your answer. How will you check that overflow menu is open right now? Secondary commands has 4 commands in it. But I want to check if menu is open right now. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Menu will always be available if you press the ellipsis, this is how the `CommandBar` works (but only if it has `SwcondaryCommands`). So if you do have `SecondaryCommands` then menu will always popup.